# How to display icon with text in html with the help of css?

Tags: html, css

**Dear All,**

I want to display icon image with text in sidebar navigation, I've tried to use vertical-align and line-height but there was no change, please see the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="MainMenu">
    <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/home.png">HOME</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Post your CSS, and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align` and `line-height`

```
<p style = 'line-height: 20px'>
  <img src = 'images/icons/home.png' style='vertical-align: middle' /> HOME
</p>
```

*Another approach*: You can use `no-repeat` for the `background`

```
span.yourtext{
  background: transparent url(images/icons/home.png) no-repeat 
              inherit left center;
  padding-left: 15px
}
<span class="yourtext">
  Home
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pseudo element` to put the icons with text. In addition I would suggest you to choose `FontAwesome` Library to choose icons (its a vector based and you can change the font icons any time). Have a look at the DEMO I've made with [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) Library. Check **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mulapuxa/1/edit)**.

**CSS Code is**

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
li{position:relative;}
li:not(.sidebar-brand):before{content:"\f015";position:absolute; left:-20px;font-family: FontAwesome;color:red;}
```